# Sybase : EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on subquery

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere, sap-iq

I'm trying to make a query that return the name of all columns for a table, and for each columns the count distinct. I have more than 1400 tables to test, with some with 100 columns, so I can't imagine tiping colomn names one by one.
I have problem for the count disctinct part, And I whant to know if it is possible to do something like an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in a subquery, and if no, if there is an other solution ?

Here is my actual query :

```
SELECT 
    sc.name AS columnName
    , ('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ' || sc.name || ') FROM MyTableName') AS nb_distinct_row  
FROM dbo.syscolumns sc INNER JOIN sysobjects so 
    ON so.id = sc.id 
    AND so.name = 'MyTableName'
GROUP BY sc.name
```

This return the good subquery but I don't know how to execute it immediatly ?
I've tried something like

```
, (SELECT count(distinct sc.name) from MyTableName) As nbDistinctRow
```

But the 'sc.name' is not interpreted and the count distinct return 1, so that's why I'm trying this way.

I work on a sybase IQ Database

Anyone can help me ?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to make this work, but it's realy clumsy.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FLA_distinctCols(in table_obj_id INT)
RESULT (column_name VARCHAR(128), count_distinct INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE err_notfound EXCEPTION FOR SQLSTATE VALUE '02000';
    DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @cols      VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @nb_dist   INT;
    DECLARE @sql       VARCHAR(30000);
    DECLARE @sqltemp       VARCHAR(30000);

DECLARE tables NO SCROLL CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 
        sc.name col
        , ('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ' || sc.name || ') INTO @nb_dist FROM ' || @tablename) 
    FROM dbo.syscolumns sc INNER JOIN sysobjects so 
        ON so.id = sc.id 
        AND so.name = @tablename 
         || '%' ORDER BY sc.name
;


SELECT so.name INTO @tablename FROM sysobjects so WHERE so.id = table_obj_id;

create table #tablestats (
    column_name       varchar(128) not null,
    count_distinct       INT,
);

open tables WITH HOLD;

LoopTables: loop

    fetch next tables into @cols, @sqltemp;

    if sqlstate = err_notfound then
        leave LoopTables
    else
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE WITH QUOTES @sqltemp;
        set @sql= 'INSERT INTO #tablestats SELECT ''' || @cols || ''', ' || @nb_dist || ';';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE WITH QUOTES @sql;
    end if

end loop LoopTables;

close tables;

SELECT column_name, count_distinct FROM #tablestats ORDER BY count_distinct DESC;

END


GO
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @tableid INT;
    SET @tablename = 'Mytablename';
    SELECT so.id INTO @tableid FROM sysobjects so WHERE so.name = @tablename;

    SELECT * FROM FLA_distinctCols(@tableid);

END
```

Any other solution ?